# Magento 2.4.x add datetime field in design configuration form using ui component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, date, design

In Magento 2.4.x, How to add date time field in Content -> Design -> Config-> HtmlHead. I tried the below code it is showing in UI(design_config_form.xml) but it is not saving.

```
    <field name="message_valid_to">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Demo Message Valid From</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">message_valid_to</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="storeTimeZone" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FInally, I found answer.
Declare the config item in `di.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\Design\Config\MetadataProvider">
    <arguments>
            <item name="message_valid_to" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="path" xsi:type="string">design/head/message_valid_to</item>
                <item name="fieldset" xsi:type="string">other_settings/head</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

Use the same item in your custom ui_component.

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="other_settings" sortOrder="30">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Other Settings</label>
    </settings>
    <fieldset name="head">
        <settings>
            <level>1</level>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">HTML Head</label>
        </settings>
    <field name="message_valid_to">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Demo Message Valid To</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">22</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">message_valid_to</item>
    <item name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="storeTimeZone" xsi:type="string">string</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

Retrieve like this:

```
 $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('design/head/message_valid_to');
```

Output:
[image]